# changing webpage randomly without getting the same page twice

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to link 35 webpages with math.random. However I dont want it to go to each site more then once. So I have this:

```
function myFunction() {
var pages = ['sang1.html', 'sang2.html', 'sang3.html', 'sang4.html', 'sang5.html', 'sang6.html', 'sang7.html', 'sang8.html', 'sang9.html', 'sang10.html', 'sang11.html', 'sang12.html', 'sang13.html', 'sang14.html', 'sang15.html', 'sang17.html', 'sang18.html', 'sang19.html', 'sang20.html', 'sang21.html'];
var page, visitedPages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("visitedPages"));
if (visitedPages === null) {
    visitedPages = [];
}
if (pages.length !== visitedPages.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        page = pages[Math.floor((Math.random() * pages.length) + 1)];
        if (visitedPages.indexOf(page) === -1) { //unvisited yet
            localStorage.setItem("visitedPages", JSON.stringify(visitedPages.push(page)));
            window.location.href = page;
            break;
        }
    }
} else {window.location.href = score.html //All pages visited at once

}
}
```

a random page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Gæt en sang</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="Test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <audio class="hidden" controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="Original GhostBusters Theme Song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
        <div id="header">
            <h2> Gæt sangen og hejs flagstangen!</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="left">
        <ul> Hvilken sang er dette?

            </br>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
            <li> Ghost busters</li>
            </button>
            </br>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
            <li> Poltergeist</li>
            </button>
            </br>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
            <li> Something strange<li>
            </button>
            </br>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
            <li> Who are you gonna call<li>
            </button>

        </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
    <p id="Test"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

so I have a button you press and then it starts myfunction. This goes for all my sites. However when i press my button it always goes to page 2. And only from page 1. Any suggestions to what is wrong?

Comment: I think that will be a problem of scope. define `page, visitedPages` outside of the `function` to make the `global`.

Comment: but i think, that is a better solution, if you just remove the already visited page from your array, if you do not want to do anything with `visitedPages` array.

Comment: it still does not seem to Work

Comment: Comment out the `window.location.href = page;` to check your errors. It sad: `TypeError: visitedPages.indexOf is not a function` And also validate your code, because it has some errors in it. `ul` can contain only `li` elements, not `br` or `divs`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a list of visited pages, have a list of all pages which you splice a random one out of on every click. An example without the finishing page:

```
var pages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pages"));

if (pages === null) {
    pages = ['sang1.html', 'sang2.html', 'sang3.html', 'sang4.html', 'sang5.html', 'sang6.html', 'sang7.html', 'sang8.html', 'sang9.html', 'sang10.html', 'sang11.html', 'sang12.html', 'sang13.html', 'sang14.html', 'sang15.html', 'sang17.html', 'sang18.html', 'sang19.html', 'sang20.html', 'sang21.html'];   
}

function onClick () {   
    var randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length),
        page = pages[randomIdx];

    pages.splice(randomIdx, 0);
    localStorage.setItem("pages", JSON.stringify(pages));

    window.location.href = page;
}
```